# How to do ssh -D in ssh config file?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to do `ssh -D 8080 root@12.105.19.126` in a ssh config file.

Currently I have tried this but it's not working correctly:

```
Host myHost
  HostName 12.105.19.126
  User root
  LocalForward localHost:8080 localHost:8080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual page of *ssh* says that `-D` is for "dynamic" forwarding.

So the corresponding option in *ssh_config* is `DynamicForward`.

```
Host myHost
  HostName 44.104.24.146
  User root
  DynamicForward 8080
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm!